# X server only starts as root

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, x-server

I have an Arch Linux system, stock kernel and drivers.
   For some strange reason, xinit produces an error when it is started by a non-root user.
   The logs say this:

```
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
```

However, I can `stat` and `ls` the file from the non-root user and the permission on it are 755

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1203780 Is your xorg the latest version? Are you using a wrapper?

Comment: Umm, on my arch-linux the permissions on `/dev/tty0` are 620, and owner is `root` and group id is `tty`. Try setting the write permission for group and see if that helps.

Answer (score 7):

Edit `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` as follow :

```
allowed_users=anybody
needs_root_rights=yes
```

[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185597)

Comment: s/Edit/Create. ⁺¹.

Comment: Just helped me on a raw Ubuntu 16.04 Server+X install, thanks.

Comment: maybe `allowed_user=console ` would be a better invocation?